# Animate text from array

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, arrays

I have this code that is supposed to take an array with some words, and apply the tweens to them, one by one, with a specified timeout. I think I have to make an empty movieclip out of them and then animate them with a foreach loop with a timeout, but I'm lost in how I would do that exactly.

This is where I'm at:

```
var array:Array = new Array("word", "is", "here");

var bounce:Function = function(mc:MovieClip):void {
mc.bounce1 = new Tween(mc, "_y", Bounce.easeOut, 35, 75, 1, true);
mc.bounce2 = new Tween(mc, "_xscale", Bounce.easeOut, 0, 400, 4, true);
mc.bounce3 = new Tween(mc, "_yscale", Bounce.easeOut, 0, 400, 4, true);
mc.bounce4 = new Tween(mc, "_alpha", Regular.easeInOut, 100, 0, 2, true);
};
array.forEach(bounce, me);
```

Could really need some assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have CS3, but I whipped up a quick example using a free tweening library called Tweener. You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/).

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;    
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
/* this is a free Tweening library. I don't have flash CS3 but this is analogous to fl.transitions.Tween */

import caurina.transitions.Tweener; 

public class Main extends MovieClip 
{
    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        /* your array of words */
        var array: Array = new Array("word", "is", "here")

        /*we'll use this to control the position of each word*/
        var x : int = 0

        var delay : Number = 0.0

        for each(var s : String in array)
        {
            var word: TextField = new TextField()
            word.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT

            /* here we can adjust text format */
            word.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat(null, 75, 0xff0000)

            word.text = s
            word.x = x
            word.y = 75

            /* put the new word into our MovieClip */
            addChild(word)

            /* apply some tweens */
            bounceText(word, delay)

            /* adjust our animation and position variables */
            delay += 1.3
            x += word.width
        }
    }

    private function bounceText(a_textField : TextField, a_delay : Number) : void
    {
        /* duration of each tween */
        var t:Number = 0.75

        /* this is the "up" part of the tween, from y=75 to y=35 */
        Tweener.addTween(a_textField, { y:35, delay:a_delay, time:t, transition:"easeOutQuad" } );

        /* this is the "down" part of the tween. note the "delay" parameter is offset by the time of the first tween.
         * the "onComplete" function calls BounceText again when the second Tween is complete. If you are using fl.transitions.Tween,
         * you can add an event listener for a TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH event, or set the "looping" property of the Tween to true.
         * */
        Tweener.addTween(a_textField, { y:75, delay:a_delay + t, time:t, transition:"easeInQuad", onComplete:bounceText, onCompleteParams:[a_textField, 0.25] } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting an error when I try to publish it. 1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.Could you post the .fla file?

Comment: I don't know much about the development environment you're using. Maybe you need to remove the "public" attribute from "class Main" ?

Comment: I'm using Flash CS4. When I remove the "public" i get a new error: 1131: Classes must not be nested.

Comment: If you're having this problem and you can't figure it out yourself, I don't know what to tell you. Can you read and understand the code? Do you know what that error message means? Is the code not enough of an example to do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Tween engine you might be able to *chain* the Tweens.
Not being sure what is your Tween engine is exactly, here's a more classical approach.
The animateNext() function is called once in the beginning and should thereafter only be invoked by your last Tweens onComplete handler (or a Timer method):

```
var wordList:Array = new Array('one','two','three');

// Keeps track of the current showing word
var currentIndex:int = -1;

// Starts the animation
animateNext();

function animateNext():void
{
   // increments the word counter
   currentIndex ++;

   // resets the word count if all the words are done
   if(currentIndex >= wordList.length)
      currentIndex = 0;

   // Apply the right word here
   var word:String = wordList[currentIndex];
   trace(word);

   // animation tweens here :
   ...

   // place callback function onComplete to animateNext()

}
```

Comment: I'm using the standard fl.transitions class. How can I can I add the text from the array to movieclips and specifiy font and size?

Comment: It depends if you want to display several texts simultaneously and if you need to apply different fonts/styles for each item, etc.